# Blessing Over Gentile Candle

Tags: mishna, tractate-brachot, candle-lighting

**Some questions arose when reading [Mishnah Brachot 8:6]**[1](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Berakhot.8.6?lang=bi&with=Talmud%20ConnectionsList&lang2=en)

> One may neither recite a blessing over the candle nor over the spices of gentiles, nor over the candle nor the spices designated to pay respects to the dead, nor over the candle nor the spices of idolatry...

- What candles are considered gentile candles?
- Does this include prohibiting gentiles from making blessings over candles in general?
- And what this have to say about the custom of, for example, lighting a candle for Rabbi Meir Baal HaNess?

Comment: It’s talking about the blessing on a candle and spices after sabbath. If it is the candle of a non Jew then it can’t be used since it used to do work on shabbos. The spices are assumed to be used for idol worship. Therefore both can’t be used for the blessing after sabbath